# ld: library not found for -lOpenCL

Tags: xcode, macos, opencl

Появляется ошибка при попытке компиляции примера на данном сайте https://www.eriksmistad.no/getting-started-with-opencl-and-gpu-computing
Компилируется через терминал, с установленным Xcode -ом, на MacBook Air 2017 где, как я понимаю, должны быть установлены библиотеки OpenCL  по умолчанию.
Команда для компиляции gcc main.c -o vectorAddition -l OpenCL

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте:

```
gcc main.c -o vectorAddition -framework OpenCL
```